# Curiosity - maximising a product with a constraint

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, problem-solving, constraints

I have integers greater than 4, for instance $i_1$, $i_2$, $i_3$, ..., $i_n$.

We have to change the greatest of these integers (for instance $i_1$ if they are ranked by descending order) by adding to it an integer constant $c$ but we need to change one or more other integers in the list $\{i_2, ..., i_n\}$ so that: (1) the sum of these integers is unchanged, that is, the sum is still equal to $\sum_{j=1}^n i_j$; (2) the product $\prod_{j=1}^n i'_j$ is maximized.

For instance we have $i_1=7$, $i_2=6$, $i_3=4$. We want to add $c=2$ to $i_1$. So we need to substract $2$ to $i_2$ or $i_3$, or to substract $1$ to $i_2$ and $i_3$, such that the sum is unchanged. It seems that the best solution is to substract $2$ to $i_2$. If we choose this solution, the product is maximized.

Is there a general method to do that ? Assuming the integers are ranked in descending order, if we want to add the constant $c$ to $i_1$ by satisfying the constraints (1) and (2) then I think the best general method is to substract $c$ to $i_2$ but how to prove this is the best solution ?

Comment: Is this a typing error "It seems that the best solution is to substract 2  to $i_1$". Didn't you just add 2 to $i_1$?

Comment: @Paul If we want to add $2$ to $i_1$, we have to substract $2$ to $i_2$ so that the sum is unchanged and the product is maximised.

Comment: I've changed a little the post for better understanding.

Comment: Reread sentence 3 in paragraph 3 :)

Comment: Exact. Thank you :-).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Note if $k> 0$, then  $a> b \iff (a-k)b > a(b-k)$.

Comment: Yes I understand when there si only one substraction, but what about the case where $c=3$ and we substract $1$ to $i_2$, substract $1$ to $i_3$ and substract $1$ to $i_4$. There are a lot of other possibilities.

Comment: All possibilities can be evaluated using the same approach sequentially, for e.g. $i_3-1 \ge i_4 \iff (i_3-2)i_4 \ge (i_3-1)(i_4-1)$ and $i_2-1 \ge i_3 \iff (i_2-3)i_3 \ge (i_2-1)(i_3-2)$ follow from the hint and covers the e.g. you mention.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you say that $i_3-1 \geq i_4$ ? The $i_j$s are in descending order but not strict, we can have $i_3=i_4$.

Comment: If they can be equal, then the same inequality suggests what to do - the solution is different.  For e.g. $(7+2)(6-2)6 \not> (7+2)(6-1)(6-1)$.  In general, you can show that a product of several numbers (with constant sum) get maximised when they can be made as close to each other as possible.

Comment: Does your hint allow to show that " In general, you can show that a product of several numbers (with constant sum) get maximised when they can be made as close to each other as possible" ?

Comment: Yes.  In essence that is exactly what the hint says.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: $c<{{i}_{j}}\,for\,1\le j\le n$ and is subtracted from only one number.
Let $P=\underset{j=1}{\overset{n}{\mathop \Pi }}\,{{i}_{j}} \\ $ and ${{P}_{k}}=({{i}_{1}}+c)\underset{j=2}{\overset{n}{\mathop \Pi }}\,i_{j}^{'} \\ $ where
$\left. i_{j}^{'}=\begin{matrix}
   {{i}_{j}}-c\,if\,\,j=k  \\
   {{i}_{j}}if\,\,j\ne k  \\
\end{matrix} \right\} \\ $

Then $\frac{{{P}_{k}}}{({{i}_{k}}-c)}=({{i}_{1}}+c)\underset{j=2,j\ne k}{\overset{n}{\mathop \Pi }}\,{{i}_{j}} \\ $ and
$ \frac{{{i}_{k}}{{P}_{k}}}{({{i}_{k}}-c)}=({{i}_{1}}+c)\underset{j=2}{\overset{n}{\mathop \Pi }}\,{{i}_{j}}=P+c\underset{j=2}{\overset{n}{\mathop \Pi }}\,{{i}_{j}}=P+\frac{cP}{{{i}_{1}}} \\ $
So that
${{P}_{k}}=P\left( 1+\frac{c}{{{i}_{1}}} \right)\left( \frac{{{i}_{k}}-c}{{{i}_{k}}} \right)=P\left( 1+\frac{c}{{{i}_{1}}} \right)\left( 1-\frac{c}{{{i}_{k}}} \right) \\
$

This is maximized for k = 2 if the numbers are in descending order. I have no idea about the other cases of subtraction from several numbers.

Comment: Thanks. As you say at the end, in fact we can have also the possibility to substract $1$ to $i_2$, $1$ to $i_3$, ..., $1$ to i_{c+1}. Such a possibility lets the sum unchanged. There are again a lot of other possibilities.